The elephent whose head attached to Lord Ganesha; Who was he? Had he got any curse in his previous life?
As we all know how Lord Ganesha's having an elephent head. But My question is that the elephent whose head was beheaded for attaching dead Ganesha's body;

Who was he?
What was his previous life?
Was he got any curse to became an elephant and will get mokshya when Lord Vishnu cut his head?
Who gave him that curse?

Is there anywhere it has been written? [Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere]
